# Toggle active state of two elements via shared data-target attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently using the function below to toggle the class of ".card-header" based on a shared data-target with it's corresponding ".seating-map_section". My hope is to adjust this so that when either the ".seating-map_section" and/or ".card-header" element is clicked, it add/removes the variable activeClass of both elements. I'm not sure what the best approach would be to something like this so any help would be greatly appreciated!

For context, this is the effect I'm going for: https://www.nba.com/timberwolves/tickets/memberships

```
  var $activeItem = $(".seating-map_section");
  var activeClass = "active";

  $activeItem.click(function() {
    const id = $(this).attr('data-target');
    const $collapse = $(`.card-header[data-target=${id}]`);

    if ($collapse) {
      $collapse.toggleClass(activeClass);
    }

    $(this).toggleClass(activeClass);
  });
```

Comment: can you give your html code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```js
 var $activeItem = $(".seating-map_section, .card-header");
 var activeClass = "active";

 $activeItem.click(function() {
   const id = $(this).attr('data-target');
   const $collapse = $(`.card-header[data-target=${id}], .seating-map_section[data-target=${id}]`);

   if ($collapse) {
     $collapse.toggleClass(activeClass);
   }
 });
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="seating-map_section" data-target="1">
Seating map section
</div>
<div class="card-header" data-target="1">
Card header
</div>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215403/discussion-on-answer-by-matthias-h-toggle-active-state-of-two-elements-via-share).

Answer (score 1):

Please look at the code below. It may work.

```
Check: http://jsfiddle.net/mehdi354/5yvds8t2/1/
```

Comment: m354 I feel like this is pretty close. For context, this is the effect I was hoping to achieve: https://www.nba.com/timberwolves/tickets/memberships. I know this was created using React, but I was hoping to create something similar with vanilla Javascript + jQuery.

Comment: you can try isotop plugin for this kind of effects. https://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Comment: I'll take a look at isotop. Might be a little outside of the current scope of the project though.